# Cluster correlations for a perfectly random state in the Alloy Theoretic Automated Toolkit

Tags: special-quasirandom-structures, alloy-theoretic-automated-toolkit

In their [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364591613000540?casa_token=4ZuPaJBAydkAAAAA:y8sN6Z0NkZ9m12eZQCgbjAa6APIYyPsMgUVuetIVeWvr8EB_RbfBpAIR9lNDdlR5wb0BfvYCHZqR), Van de Walle et al. describe how their code `mcsqs` treats cluster correlations in the algorithm to generate special quasirandom structures (SQS). In the third section, titled 'Algorithm', they describe how cluster correlations in a perfectly random state are determined. Somehow I can't seem to understand the equation. Can someone help me understand it?

If a responder wishes to use illustrations, a perfect test case would be the correlation for nearest neighbour (NN) pairs.

Answer (score 3):

**Caution: Self answer ahead!**

Let's understand it with an example of a binary $AB$ compound.

A correlation function for a particular type of cluster (pair, triangle, tetrahedron, etc.), $\rho$, is defined as

\begin{equation}
\rho_\alpha\: =\: <cluster function>_\alpha,\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Where $\alpha$ represents the type of cluster and $<...>$ represents an average over all clusters equivalent to $\alpha$ by symmetry.

\begin{equation}
cluster function = \prod_i{\gamma_{\alpha_i,M_i}}_{(\sigma_i)} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

The cluster function is a product of a quantity which in the sense of binary alloys is called a spin variable (inspired by the Ising model), whereas, in general, for multicomponent systems seems to have no name. The paper cited in the question denotes it as $\gamma_{\alpha_i,M_i}$, where $i$ represents a lattice point, $\alpha_i$ takes two values, 0 for when $i$ is not in a certain cluster and 1 when it is, and $M_i$ is simply the number of type of atoms, 2 for binary, 3 for ternary, and so on. *Note: $\alpha$ and $\alpha_i$ aren't the same.*

Convention: $\gamma$ equals 1 for any site $i$ that isn't part of the particular cluster $\alpha$ ($\alpha_i\: =\: 0$).

$\sigma_i$ in equation 2 is an occupation variable which holds the information about which atom occupies lattice site $i$. It takes values from $0$ to $M_i - 1$. For example, in a ternary alloy, $\sigma_i\: =\: 0, 1,$ or $2$.

\begin{equation}
\sigma_i\: =\:
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{atom A on i}\\
    +1, & \text{atom B on i}
\end{cases}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Let's calculate the pair correlation for $AB$:

$\alpha\: =\: 2$ (pair)

$M_i\: =\: 2$ (binary)

In a perfectly random phase, each lattice point $i$ is equally likely to be occupied by $A$ and $B$ since it is an equiatomic alloy.

$\alpha_i$ will be $0$ for all lattice points that aren't in the particular pair we are calculating the cluster function for and $1$ for those that are part of the pair. So the four possible values of ${\gamma_{\alpha_i,M_i}}_{(\sigma_i)}$ for a binary are:

${\gamma_{0,2}}_{(0)}\: =\: 1$

${\gamma_{0,2}}_{(1)}\: =\: 1$

${\gamma_{1,2}}_{(0)}\: =\: -1$

${\gamma_{1,2}}_{(1)}\: =\: +1$

In a random phase of $AB$, every lattice site $i$ on average has a $0.5$ occupation of $A$ and $0.5$ of $B$. To calculate the correlation function, $\rho_\alpha$, we need to take an average of cluster functions for all equivalent clusters $\alpha$. Every pair (even higher clusters) in a perfectly random phase is equivalent, so all cluster functions are the same and equal to the average, hence equal to the correlation function.

The value of ${\gamma_{1,2}}_{(\sigma_i = 0,1)}\: =\: 0.5\cdot (-1) + 0.5\cdot (+1) = 0$ for each site $i$.

So the cluster function for a pair which contains two lattice points $=\: 0\cdot 0\: = 0$.

Finally, the correlation function, $\rho_2$, is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Sachania why does the generated SQS have no symmetry?